# What is a given data from a problem called?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Greek we say δεδομένα. I don't know what it is called in English or I've just forgotten.

For example, a maths exercise when a value *x* is given to calculate *y*.

When a problem gives us  data and requires to solve a problem, what is that data called?

Comment: AFAIK "data" is Latin, not Greek.

Comment: @WeatherVane δεδομένα is greek not data

Comment: 'Problems' do not generate data. It is documented events or documented observations that create data.

Comment: Please add an example to your question. Without further context, it looks very much like ordinary *data*.

Comment: A maths exercise when it is given  a value x to calculate y for example

Comment: You might get a more helpful response on the Math SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions . Personally (and I'm no mathematician) -- I call the different parts of math problems, "elements" or "factors". But don't take my word for it. I looked, and couldn't find a satisfactory answer. There is also: subtrahend, dividend, minuend, etc. But I couldn't figure out what those are called collectively.

Comment: In a programming context, you might consider *x* to be an *input* to produce *y*, but *data* works better in a maths context. Why is *data* not sufficiently descriptive for what you have in mind?

Comment: (By the way, on SE, comments to a post produce notifications to its author, but unlabelled comments may not ping others. Please continue using the "@" convention.)

Comment: Is "parameter" the word you're looking for?  (Your question is very unclear.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Data* is in fact the Latin translation of Greek δεδομένα. Both are participles meaning, literally, "given" (plural), and as nominals that's the oldfashioned English translation: they are the "givens" of the problem. But you'll more often find it as the head of a participle phrase:

> **Given** two points with the coordinates *x<sub>1</sub>y<sub>1</sub>* and *x<sub>2</sub>y<sub>2</sub>*, find the slope of the line which passes through them.

Comment: So they are called givens?

Comment: @csandreas1 Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

In software, these can be termed parameters. In some non-software contexts **parameters** may still make sense.

> In computer programming, a parameter (often called formal parameter or formal argument) is a special kind of variable, used in a subroutine to refer to one of the pieces of data provided as input to the subroutine.[a] These pieces of data are the values of the arguments (often called actual arguments or actual parameters) with which the subroutine is going to be called/invoked.
>   — [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming))

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like you may be asking about "terms":

> [**term**](http://www.storyofmathematics.com/glossary.html#T://): in an algebraic expression or equation, either a single **number or variable**, or the product of several numbers and variables separated from another term by a + or - sign, **[example:]** in the expression 3 + 4x + 5yzw, **the 3, the 4x and the 5yzw are all separate terms**.

This definition of a mathematical term ironically known as ***term*** clearly explains that the *numbers and variables* in any equation are called the **terms** of the equation, while the symbols indicating the operations required to solve the problem are *not* called terms.